After 4 rounds of interviews the salary range is lower than expected, even when I shared my current situation
After four rounds of interviews (even finally meeting the CEO) at an American multinational company the HR contact me to talk about salary expectations.
I have shared in all my interviews (except with the CEO) my current salary and so I'm extremely surprised to discovered just now that the salary maximum is around 10k less than my current situation.
I am ok to change to this new opportunity with my same salary, but not to lower it.
I don't know how much this is a negotiating technique or if they're telling the truth.
It feels such a waste of time from their side to keep me doing interviews if my current salary already was 10k above their maximum.
Any recommendations on my next step with my conversation with HR?
They're expecting me to give them a number.

Was the pay range provided up front and, if so, is the offered number within that range? In the USA it's common practice for companies to include a salary range with the job posting, and in my opinion it's a red flag if they don't.

"They're expecting me to give them a number."  And the problem with doing that is...???

Where are you located? In some US jurisdictions (like my home state of Illinois) it's illegal for employers to ask about current salary. (If you offered it on your own, that's your business.)  If the employer is cheap with you now, don't ever expect them to get better.


Make sure you understand the full package of the offer: base, bonus (amount, timing, and rules), sign-on, benefits, pensions, 401k matching, equity, relocation, etc. Typically there is way more to a compensation package than just the base salary. It's important to compare total compensation.
If the total comp is lower than you current gig, bring it up with HR. You can always tell them that you are excited about the opportunity, but that you are not actively looking for a pay cut.
If you are fine with pay parity, just say so. Let them know that they need to at least match your current total comp. That's not an unreasonable request.
Consider some flexibility in the comp structure. Maybe you can accept a lower base salary if the bonus is higher or they throw in a good chunk of equity.


They're expecting me to give them a number.

Give them number that you are willing to accept. Or said differently: tell them the number that's your no-go bar. Anything less, and you walk (but be prepared to actually walk if they can't hit it). Again you can make the discussion more broadly about total compensation. In stead of throwing out a single number you can give a few different options.

I totally agree, doesn't sound like OP has made their position clear at all. From the employer's point of view, they have made it clear what their offer is and OP keeps going back. There are a number of reasons people change employment, it is easy to assume that OP might have left a bad work environment and is willing to work for less if the conditions are better. If their offer is too low, tell them what you want and don't settle for less, have some respect for yourself.

You should be looking for an amount greater than you currently make because most American companies will lowball you like this. If you provided them a higher amount at the start, their lowball offer could potentially be within your actual desired range. Companies will also claim that there's a chance for promotion or a raise once you get to know their industry or products, but I would not count on it. Recruiters may say anything to get you in the door and make their numbers or commissions. If it isn't in the contract, it isn't guaranteed.

@Hilmar While actively looking for a pay cut is definitely unusual, being prepared to accept one is not uncommon particularly if you are changing fields. I've twice willingly taken pay cuts in my life. Once when leaving a temporary contract that involved hazard and overtime pay for a more conventional and safer role and once when changing career fields.

@Hilmar the golden rule in job interviews (and life) is to never safe to assume anything... Especially when negotiating a contract. From an employer's point of view, they may be trying to fill a specific role and budget. Your advice for computing and comparing the total compensation or overall return is good though, its not always dollars for dollars

+1 So many different forms of compensation, and truth be told past a certain dollar value the non dollar benefits often matter more. PTO, overtime compensation (dollars or extra PTO...)

Point 2 just sounds sarcastic to me, but I'm not used to the US way of speaking https://imgflip.com/i/9fahco

Your own claim already answers your own question:

I am ok to change to this new opportunity with my same salary, but now to lower it.

Based on this quote your decision is very simple; if the salary is lower, then reject. If the salary is not lower, then accept.
The fact that you are even posting this question makes me question the validity of your claim:

I don't know how much this is a negotiating technique or if you're telling the truth.

Is your claim in the first quote really true? It seems there are other factors at play, otherwise you would not be asking this question. There are perfectly valid reasons to accept a pay cut, and it seems you might have some reasons. I would advise you to make clear to yourself which factors you are weighing in this decision.


Any recommendations on my next step with my conversation with HR?
They're expecting me to give them a number.

So give them a number!
Something like: "I like what I've seen so far, but not the salary. I can't accept less than [X]". Make sure X is the minimum you need to make you happy about accepting the job offer.
And if they still offer less, thank them for their time and walk away.
Simple.

It is quite possible that someone in the company thinks offering you less would help the company.
If you are employed and not really unhappy in your position, or expecting to be laid off you’d want at least a few percent more for the inconvenience of changing jobs (taking everything into account). So you can tell them “my current salary is X, and I won’t start for less than Y” or just “I won’t start for less than Y, so I expect an offer of Y or more”.
And common sense is that if they offer/pay just your minimum you might continue looking for something better, and/or leave as soon as you find something better. You won’t be too motivated and hard working. They don’t save money by lowballing you. And maybe the people you are actually working for have no idea about this low offer.
